# What are the default margin and padding on grids - BOOTSTRAP 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been searching for some answer about this.

Bootstrap 4 were measured via ems and rems: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/

Now I wanna know what are the default margin and padding on each grids.

It may also talk about the gutter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gutter width is 30px (15px on each side of a column) in bootstrap 4 as it was in bootstrap 3.

for more information [read](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options)

> Padding left and right for column will be 15px each side,  where as
>   margin left and margin right for row is -15px.

Comment: So how was it 15px margin and padding? is that what you mean can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Also is there a class in Bootstrap 4 that will say if there is a "Special class" that will remove the gutter?